# Passing a navigation prop results in undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I am getting the error "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')" when I try to use the navigate function from the navigation object in my React Native app.

The code that is causing the error is:

```
const TrackerSettings = (input) => {
const [navigation, setNavigation] = useState(input);

const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

const handleSelected = (value) => {
setSelected(value);
console.log(value);
//Console.log logs the navigation as it should
console.log(navigation);
// The navigate function call is here
navigation.navigate("Tracker");
//Here i get an error where navigation.navigate is undefined.
};

return (
<View style={styles.container}>
<Text style={styles.locationDesc}>Choose a location:</Text>
<View style={styles.buttonRow}>
<LocationAndPriceCard
title={"1"}
onPress={handleSelected}
value={selected}
/>
<LocationAndPriceCard
title={"2"}
onPress={handleSelected}
value={selected}
/>
</View>
<View style={styles.buttonRow}>
<LocationAndPriceCard
title={"3"}
onPress={handleSelected}
value={selected}
/>
<LocationAndPriceCard
title={"4"}
onPress={handleSelected}
value={selected}
/>
</View>
</View>
);
};

export default TrackerSettings;
```

Output from Console.log:

```
{"navigation": {"addListener": [Function addListener], "canGoBack": [Function canGoBack], "dispatch": [Function dispatch], "getId": [Function getId], "getParent": [Function getParent], "getState": [Function anonymous], "goBack": [Function anonymous], "isFocused": [Function isFocused], "jumpTo": [Function anonymous], "navigate": [Function anonymous], "pop": [Function anonymous], "popToTop": [Function anonymous], "push": [Function anonymous], "removeListener": [Function removeListener], "replace": [Function anonymous], "reset": [Function anonymous], "setOptions": [Function setOptions], "setParams": [Function anonymous]}}
```

I am still getting the error. Can anyone help me to fix it?

Probably some silly mistake, but im still learning react/react-native

Comment: I know you said that the `console.log(navigation)` logs as it should. Could you let me know that actual output? Thanks

Comment: Added output as an edit :)

Comment: I'm probably going to sound stupid here but if the output of `console.log(navigation)` is that output do you need to access the navigate funciton by  `navigation.navigation.navigate`

Comment: Correct.

Basicly im trying to navigate from a button inside a component in Stack Sceen, hence passing the Navigation prop to call in from the child screen.

Comment: But you trying to run it as `navigation.navigate` not `navigation.navigation.navigate`?

Comment: `navigation` doesn't have a `navigate` field.  It has a `navigation` field, which has a `navigate` field.  IE `navigation.navigation.navigate()`

Comment: Ahaa. 
That worked perfectly!

Just to understand:
im sending in a navigation variable, that variable has a object called navigation which has the function navigate()

But my error was that i tried to call navigate() on the variable and not on the object?

Comment: Pretty much. You could look either change how you pass the prop in to the component or change `useState(input)` to `useState(input.navigation)` so you could then use navigation.navigate() as you originaly intended

Comment: Thank you very much :) 

How do i give you credit for the answer?

Comment: I tried to consolidate into an answer. I also added an option to not use useState for `navigation` but this depends on your useage. From what I can see you may just be able to use it as the prop being passed in and not need useState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved through the comments above but here is an easy to digest version

From the log: `console.log(navigation);` we can see the console output is of the form

```
{"navigation": { ... , "navigate": [Function anonymous], ... }}
```

So navigation is actually an object containing an object with the key "navigation" which contains "navigate". This means `navigation.navigate` is undefined

## Solutions

### Option 1

- Access navigate using `navigation.navigation.navigate("Tracker")`

### Option 2

- Change `useState(input)` to `useState(input.navigation)`
- This allows the intended call of the function through `navigation.navigate("Tracker");`

### Option 3

- This option depends on how you intend to use the `navigation` in useState
- As your component is getting the navigation through a prop it isn't really necessary to use useState from what I can see
- Use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of your passed in object then access it as intended

```
const TrackerSettings = ({navigation}) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

    const handleSelected = (value) => {
        setSelected(value);
        //Console.log logs the navigation as it should
        console.log(navigation);
        // The navigate function call is here
        navigation.navigate("Tracker");
```